# Insert 70 Million Reoced in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have around `70 Million` record in files, and i have to read all the record and insert it into `MYSQL` database. I take about `2 days` to insert all the data, the issue is that now i have to add few conditions before adding them to the database. But when i add condition it take more days to complete. And this process is done `every week`. So if it take 4 days to read and sort the data in 7 days week, then there will be no use of it.

Is there any quick why so that it take less time to read the data.

Current File size: `500MB`

The main condition is that when i read the data and it not meat the requirement then that data store in an other table.

`I have an other option as well for this.` If this will not done. I have to show data in front-end after the insertion. Let's suppose there is no quick way to minimize the time. so after the insertion of all data, i have to show this data on `front-end` and `100` records per page, so is there any way i make condition in pagination that it will show only 100 record which meat my requirements and next `100` which meat requirements.

Let suppose i Read `100` record and in 100 there is only 80 record which meat my requirements. so that 1st page must pull `20` more record which meat my requirements.

Here is The example of the data and how it show work

```
master_account_number,sub_account_number,current_balance,first_name,last_name,city,state,zip,client_id

01-962040041,01-000050003,11.25,IRENE,AULTMAN,MICHELLVILLE,MD,20721,000969
```

I need this format for every row. If any `field is empty` it will be consider as a `bad data` and store in other table. Or if format of the data not match then it also consider as a `bad data`. If balance is `zero` then also bad data, and many more conditions as well.

i am using

```
Codeigniter 
IIS 7 Server
MYSQL
```

Storing all data as a string

And i use this query to load the data into `DB`.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\www.suburbancredit.com\\csv\\atest.csv'
INTO TABLE accounts
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(`accountNumber`, `caseNumber`, `current_balance`, `first_name`, `last_name` , `city`, `state`, `zip`, `client_id`)
```

Comment: What kind of conditions? The question has a PHP tag: Do you use a PHP script? If yes: can you show us the essential (short) part of it? Just guessing: disable indexes while importing; use prepared statements; ...but those are only the low hanging fruits; you have to tell us more specifics.

Comment: Please provide some of code your have tried.

Comment: this is interesting, please give more details about the files, each line and conditions, also the target database structure, server details

Comment: I just edit my question you can check it.

Comment: Use a unix socket (significanly less overhead than http(s)). use a transaction. use prepared statement. in php, PDO is faster than MySQLi iirc, so use PDO. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite , even though its for SQLite, much of it is valid for MySQL too.

Comment: @hanshenrik From the looks of it, he's using a windows machine :/

Comment: @Populus oh, then add Linux to the list of optimizations ;)

Comment: this may be relevant: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31752/mysql-load-data-infile-slows-by-80-after-a-few-gigs-of-input-with-innodb-engine

Comment: @hanshenrik the issue is that how can i fast the procedure of checking data, when i put conditions and check then it slow down the whole process. Currently by using this it store data in 5min, But when add PHP condition it dead slow.

Comment: maybe look into multithreading it (PHP has excelent threading support these days with pthreads), or rewriting this heavy opreation in a fast language, like C (or assembly ;) ) lets say you make cpus+1 worker threads, and assing chunks of records to each of these workers~?